# My coolpad note 3 lite is not switching on

Tags: power-on

It is off and i cannot switch it on. While charging i press power button nothing happens only the led glows to show charging. It is not getting recovery mood also.
I think power button might got defected. I don't know. Please help me fast and urgent.

Comment: if you use an sd card try discarding it and then switch on then you can now power on your phone

Answer (score 0):

Do you have dropped it? Probably power button can be broken then. If not then try to find a reset switch lot of tablets have a small hole labeled as reset where you can insert a small pin and holding it will reset your tablet. This problem constantly happens with me but resting it helps. Don't worry none of your data will be affected.

Comment: Isn't that a rear microphone??

Comment: It will be labeled as reset not mic

Comment: ther is nothing to reset in coolpad note 3 lite

Comment: I think you should to try to fix that power button. If it still won't work then try reinstall firmware.